# Difference between the toolchains of android

Tags: android, kernel, toolchain, android-kernel

There are many different types of toolchains available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/). But I cannot understand which one to use for what. I understood that `arm` toolchains should be used for compiling 32-bit architectures.But there are differen `arm` toolchains. But again `x86` toolchains are also available. Basically I want to understand the difference between the `aarch64`, `arm`, `host`, `mips` and `x86`. Till now I had been trying all the toolchains for a particular source code and try all of them, but it was hectic task. For example, I extracted the source code from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/arm64/+/android-easel-intel-linux-4.7-oreo-m4) and `aarch64` compiled the source code successfully and I dont understand why? How do I decide which `toolchain` should be used for which kernel source?

Comment: What for? You just need the one for you hardware architecture, needed ABI And host computer if you cross compile.You can usually compile the code with any compiler, but the resulting code will not be very useful. For example if you compile cortex m1code using x86compiler

Comment: For `arm64` architecture, which one is the toolchain that I should use? Is it `arm` or `aarch64`

Comment: Relations between `arm64` and `aarch64` are described in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851611/differences-between-arm64-and-aarch64. Its answers say that both term refers to the same hardware. So, for `arm64` architecture you may use `aarch64` toolchain.

Comment: OK. I understood for `arm64` architecture. But for `arm`, there are `arm-eabi-4.x`  and `arm-linux-androideabi-4.x`. Similarly for `x86`, there are  `i686-linux-android-4.7` and `x86_64-linux-android-4.7`. What's the difference?