# OSError: file.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I have built an .so file used in our python package. We use the package on Dietpi 64bits. When I import our package I get the error:

```
OSError: file.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know for a fact that the file is there and the path is good.

What is puzzling me is that when I try the same code on a Virtual Machine (also Diepi 64bit), the dynamic library is found and loaded properly. I did that to try an isolate the difference between my setup and my colleague's setup.

- File exists
- Same location in both cases
- File has the same rights (chmod 777)
- He is using python 3.6, while VM 3.7

What am I missing?
What can cause the OS to raise a No such file or directory exception when the directory DOES exists and file IS there?

---

### Edit

Here is the code that I'm using

```
import os
import ctypes

shared_library_name = "libFoo"

print("current working directory: {}\n".format(os.getcwd()))
current_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/natives/")
os.chdir(current_path)
current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

path_to_so = os.path.abspath(current_path + "/" + shared_library_name + ".so")
print("new current_path: ", current_path)
print("\n path_to_so: {}\n".format(path_to_so))
# prints the right path with the right file, and I can cd to it in the terminal

print("path exist {}".format(os.path.isdir(current_path)))
print("file exist {}\n".format(os.path.isfile(path_to_so)))
# prints False

dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(path_to_so)
# fails saying that the file is not there...
```

Comment: how do you start you program?

Comment: Either a script in python or Python in the terminal

Comment: you could pass strace on your call and see if it is not an error reported by the loader of a lib of a second level (a so needed by a so you call explicitely)

Comment: strace doesnt seem to indicate any missing .so or obvious errors

Comment: Can somebody explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared library that I was trying to open was not build for the architecture used by your Virtual Machine.

aarch64 vs x84_64

When I asked the question, I was not aware that my target (NanoPi Neo2) needed different flags than the virtual machine when building the shared library.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461179/what-is-the-difference-between-different-implemetation-of-arm64-aarch64-for-lin

[Differences between arm64 and aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851611/differences-between-arm64-and-aarch64)