# Linux - Can I run arm64 binaries on aarch64 architecture?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm64

arm64 and aarch64 are supposed to be the same thing (or not?). I got my Ubuntu architecture aarch64 using

`uname --m`

But most binary launcher of apps are in arm64. 
Is there any way to run arm64 apps(binaries) on aarch64?

Answer (score 2):

See [Differences between arm64 and aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851611/differences-between-arm64-and-aarch64/47274698#47274698). AArch64 and arm64 are the same thing. Does executing the binary not work for you?

Comment: Executing binary doesnt work on most files. Only difference I see is architechture of file vs my system.

Answer (score -6):

These are the simple steps, Please try with these steps.

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt-get update (ignore the missing x386 packages and hope for the best)
apt-get install libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf
```

Comment: Well, didn't work. Still says ```bash: Cannot execute binary file```

Comment: @AsDf What are you trying to run and how?

Comment: trying to run Godot Engine file type : ``` ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=e34380876fe35a0c6c6b49a5872c89e5874bc14d, with debug_info, not stripped
``` file has been given executing permission

Comment: `x86-64/amd64` architecture  is not  `arm64/aarch64` architecture - this is why you are getting an (accurate) error message.

Comment: @ Arpit Jain: IMHO, `armhf`  is 32 bits arm + hardware floating point support, and not `arm64`/`aarch64` - this will not solve As Df's problem.

Comment: @AsDf: any thoughts?

Comment: @Frant: well, maybe it means i need to add amd64 architecture for the mentioned file type.

Comment: Uh, adding amd64 doesn't do it,