# PHP how to detect if running on arm64 cpu?

Tags: php, arm64

In PHP how can I detect if I am running on an arm64 CPU or not? (as opposed to, for example, an AMD64 CPU)

Comment: why should it even matter to php which one you're running? PHP is server dependent, not processor dependent - i.e. the code compiles on any server running php which is processor independent?

Comment: @DannyF have some code that normally runs `passthru("docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml build");` but on arm64 cpus it needs to run the slightly different command `passthru("docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.arm64.yml build");`

Answer (score 2):

The solution seems to be php_uname("m"), but it is trickier than one would expect. This is because we have observed different values for php-running-on-macos (PHP 8.1.3, "arm64") versus php-running-in-linux-docker-container-running-on-macos (PHP 7.4.28, "aarch64"), sooo we have to check for both???

```
// have been in a situation where MacOS-php says 
// "arm64" while php-in-docker-linux-container-running-on-macos
// says "aarch64"...
$isArm64 = (false!==stripos(php_uname("m"), "aarch64") || false!== stripos(php_uname("m"),"arm64"));
```

Comment: Does this work correctly for an x86_64 PHP binary running in Rosetta on arm64? I know `uname -m` on the command line doesn't...

Comment: [Differences between arm64 and aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851611/differences-between-arm64-and-aarch64)

Comment: @Siguza unfortunately i have no idea. if you have such a php-cli binary nearby, run ```php -r 'var_dump(php_uname("m"));'``` and let us know :) (my best guess is that php_uname reports ```AMD64``` under Rosetta, but I don't know.)

Comment: PHP 8 (tested with 8.0.28) also reports "aarch64" when running`php -r 'var_dump(php_uname("m"));'` so this snippet also works with php 8 in rosetta docker.