# How to change the architecture of armv7l (yocto) to arm64/aarch64?

Tags: architecture, yocto, arm64, raspberry-pi4

I have installed Yocto image in the Raspberry Pi 4B previously and I know that the current architecture is armv7l by using uname -m. However, I want to change the architecture to ARM64/AARCH64.
Anyone knows how to configure it?
By the way, ARM64 and AARCH64 are the same thing, right?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851611/differences-between-arm64-and-aarch64), it is exactly the same thing. It's just a different notation based on the used compiler (LLVM => arm64 or GNU => aarch64)
.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by changing the machine type to "raspberrypi4-64", and it works fine now.